# How to create an abstract activity class and extend it to all activities?

Tags: java, android

I have navigation drawer menu and 6 activities. I want to create an abstract activity class, and move all my drawer menu code to it, and then extend it.

This is my Main activity.java and my drawer's code in this activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface textfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/B Roya_YasDL.com.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(textfont);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.a1);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_more_vert_black_24dp);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.a2);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            item.setChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.intro:
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
            }



            return false;
        }
    });

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.khat) {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }

        else {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"somthing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    return true;
}

public void onBackPressed(){
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }else {super.onBackPressed();}

}
```

and this is my second activity for example:

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);
}
```

How can I create an abstract activity class and insert my drawer's code in there and call it from any activity that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create mainActivity like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    public NavigationView navigationView;
    public DrawerLayout drawer;
    public RelativeLayout content;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawer=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);

        navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);




    }


    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, null);
        //  var x = layout.LayoutParameters;
        content.addView(layout);
    }


    public void OpenDrawer()
    {
        drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START,true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.navdrawer_item_first:
                Toast.makeText(this, "first item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.navdrawer_item_second:
                Toast.makeText(this, "second item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:drawer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        drawer:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items"
        drawer:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        android:background="#343a46"
        drawer:itemTextColor="#ffffff" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

then you will extend Mail Activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    }
}
```

and in Manifest make second activity is the launcher:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>s
        </activity>
```

Comment: you will find navigation_drawer_items and drawer_header in another answer as i forgot them

Comment: Note that you can edit answers, so if your two items should go together, edit one to include the other, and then delete the spare one.

Comment: Thank you. i solved my problem with an idea that came from your answer. thank you very much

Comment: Thanks Halfer , i will do that next time

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend making a abstract activity for this purpose.
Instead you should have just one activity where your navigation drawer is attached.And replace your activities with fragments except for MainActivity which would contain the navigation drawer.

`activity_main` layout would looks like:

`-DrawerLayout
   -FrameLayout
   -NavigationView`

And in the main activity whenever user clicks on any of the item in NavigationDrawer just replace the fragment with the required one.

Answer (score 0):

navigation_drawer_items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/group_feature"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/navdrawer_item_first"


            android:title="first item"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/navdrawer_item_second"


            android:title="second item"/>

    </group>

</menu>
```

drawer_header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#343a46"

    android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="10dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:textColor="#dfba6b"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```